# How to put list values with single quotes as well as double quotes to Postgressql Select Query

Tags: python-3.x, postgresql

I'm Executing select query to postgresql database and after fetching those results I'm appending those results to list and then I'm giving that list as the input to another postgresql select query.

But due to conversion of those values to list it converts values with apostrophe(special character) `cat's` to double quotes `"cat's"`. while executing second select query the value with double quotes is not been fetched because value with double quotes is not present in the database it is without double quotes `cat's`.
And there it gives me error that value is not present.

I have tried JSON dumps method but its isn't working because I cannot convert JSON list to tuple and give it as the input to postgresql select query

```
select_query = """select "Unique_Shelf_Names" from "unique_shelf" where category = 'Accessory'"""
cur.execute(select_query)
count = cur.fetchall()

query_list = []
for co in count:
    for c in co:
        query_list.append(c)
```

output of `query_list`:

```
query_list = ['parrot', 'dog', "leopard's", 'cat', "zebra's"]
```

Now this `querylist` is been converted to tuple and given as the input to another select query.

```
list2 = tuple(query_list)

query = """select category from  "unique_shelf" where "Unique_Shelf_Names" in {} """.format(list2)

cur.execute(query)
```

This is where it gives me error `"leopard's" doesn't exist` but in database leopard's exists.

I want all the values in the `query_list` to be double quotes so this error doesn't arises.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do not use `format` to construct the query. Simply use `%s` and pass the tuple into `execute`

```
query = """select category from  "unique_shelf" where "Unique_Shelf_Names" in %s """

cur.execute(query,(list2,))
```

[Tuples adaptation](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/usage.html#tuples-adaptation)

Comment: Thanks for your reply but list formatting is not an issue

Comment: @Shubham : Please try the option I mentioned in my answer and let me know if it doesn't work. Also, the link I posted clearly mentions how to pass values as tuples to the `IN` clause. So, if you want to use `format`, it means you're using the incorrect method.

Comment: Sorry kaushik i thought formatting was not an issue. Thanks alot you solved my problem.

Comment: @Shubham : You're welcome. I'm glad I was able to help.